# Как сделать одновременное нажатие клавиш в selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hotkeys

Если коротко, то нужно вызвать **Responsive Design Mode** из **selenium'а**, я хотел использовать вариант зажатия горячих клавишь, то бишь **ctrl+shift+m**, я использую следующий код:

```
ActionChains(self.driver)   \
            .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
            .key_down(Keys.SHIFT)   \
            .send_keys("m")         \
            .key_up(Keys.CONTROL)   \
            .key_up(Keys.SHIFT)   \
        .perform()
```

Так же я пробовал следующий код:

```
body = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + 'm')
```

Код выполняется без ошибок, однако ничего не происходит, в чем проблема ? Либо есть другой вариант вызова этого режима из-под **selenium'a** ?

Answer (score 1):

Через chromedriver открыть не получится. Можно воспользоваться
[Auto-open DevTools on every new tab](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/open?tabs=cmd-Windows#auto-open-devtools-on-every-new-tab) или посылать сочетания клавиш из других библиотек.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('http://ya.ru')
```

Comment: А для Firefox как можно установить ?